# Wireless Disabled in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

I recently disabled Networking in my laptop (Acer Aspire V5); it turns on in no way. I reboot several times, I tried keyboard command, edit connection, enable networking of course; via terminal I run some commands I found in askubuntu but they obviously don't work because there is no internet connection in the laptop. I tried rfkill and lshw althoughy I don't know how to go forward.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command. And also make sure you did not turn off wifi by a hardware switch.

Comment: I tried "autoremove" and "autoclean" then reboot and it now works.  (I know modern informatics corresponds to sorcery in the past) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think I once solved it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and then rebooting.